# Django form for model

Tags: django, forms, widget

with Django forms you can specify widget:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(
        max_length = 30,
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {'class':'text required email', 'id':'email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs = {'class':'text required', 'id':'password', 'minlength':'4'}))
```

is it possible to do that in models?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    name =              models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    phone =             models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    email =             models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    start =             models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    destination =           models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    size =              models.CharField(max_length = 256)
```

I'd love to use this (specify CSS class) when creating form for model like:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method to specify a css class:

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for adding issues."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['class'] = "span-3 last"
```

Let me know if you need more — Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can redefine widget by overriding the fields in your modelform.

Another approach would be to implement `__init__` method and change the widget or attr in the existing fields.